# Laravel 5.4 Model::where not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models

I'm a bit new to laravel and try to do a simple thing, just trying to select multiple rows with eloquent and tried :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use App\Company;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Model;

class BaseController extends Controller {


    public function __construct() {

            //$companies = Company::find(1);
            //$companies = Company::all();
            $companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id);
                print_r($cpm);
            View::share ( 'companies', '$companies' );
    }

}
```

But always get this error :

> ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object in BaseController.php (line 16)

And 2 commented lines above are working fine, so i'm a bit lost?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Are you logged in when you get this error?

Comment: Huhu...of course not :D

Comment: side comment you can use `dd($companies)` instead of `print_r()`

Comment: Where the `$cpm` variable came from?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct() {

        //$companies = Company::find(1);
        //$companies = Company::all();
        $companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id);
            print_r($cpm);
        View::share ( 'companies', '$companies' );
}
```

This piece:

```
$companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id);
```

Needs to change into this:

```
 $companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

The get makes sure your sql gets runned, and the output us returned to $companies.

And I believe

```
 View::share ( 'companies', '$companies' );
```

needs to be:

```
 View::share ( 'companies', $companies );
```

resulting in:

```
public function __construct() {

        //$companies = Company::find(1);
        //$companies = Company::all();
        $companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
            print_r($cpm);
        View::share ( 'companies', $companies );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the ID of a loggedin user when no user is logged in. So you should check if a user is logged.

I advice you to use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware).

You can also check if the user is logged in using:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $companies = Company::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
}
```

Read this for more information about Authentication: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Answer (score 0):

The `where()` method returns a [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where) object and not the result of the query. You need to call [`get()` method](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) in order to get an exploitable Collection.